# How to get combination result by one column history sql snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, logic, method-combination

I have a table history task of user, seems like this. 1 user have 9 task.

```
user_id     task    IS_COMPLETED updated_at
123       Task 1    1            2024-01-01
123       Task 2    1            2024-01-01
123       Task 3    0            2024-01-01
123       Task 4    0            2024-01-01
123       Task 5    0            2024-01-01
123       Task 6    1            2024-01-01
123       Task 7    1            2024-01-01
123       Task 8    1            2024-01-01
123       Task 9    1            2024-01-01
```

I want to grouping with possible combination of the task, to become table like this. So I know what kind of task combinations are quickly completed by users.

```
combination     total_user_completed
task1_task2         20
task1_task3         15 
task1_task_4        15
task1_task_5        14
:                    : (and so on for 2 combination) 
task1_task2_task3   10
task4_task5_task_6  11
:                   : (and so on for 3 combination)
```

(for more detail about combination example: from A,B,C i got combination between A-B,B-C,A-C, and A-B-C. No need to be sequential)

I have tried with recursive sql but it didn't work well

> "Recursive Join ran out of memory. Please re-run this query on a
> larger warehouse"

Then I also try to make it with case when, but it's not ideal i need to define one by one like this.

```
    with all_task as (
            select 
                distinct user_id,
                task_name as task, 
                is_completed,
                updated_at
            from task
            where 
                is_completed = 1
            group by all
          ),
        agg as (
            select 
                distinct user_id, 
                activated_at as period,
                max(case when task in ('Task 1') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_1,
                max(case when task in ('Task 2') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_2,
                max(case when task in ('Task 3') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_3,
                max(case when task in ('Task 4') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_4,
                max(case when task in ('Task 5') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_5,
                max(case when task in ('Task 6') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_6,
                max(case when task in ('Task 7') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_7,
                max(case when task in ('Task 8') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_8,
                max(case when task in ('Task 9') and IS_COMPLETED = 1 then date(updated_at) end) as task_9
            from all_task 
            group by all
            ),
            task_group as (
            select user_id, 
                case when task_1 is not null and task_2 is not null then user_id end as task_1_2
                case when task_2 not null and task_3 is not null then user_id end as task_2_3
                .........
            from agg
             )
            select 'Task1_task2' as combination, 
            count(distinct task_1_2) as total
            from task_group

            union all 

            select 'task2_task3' as combination, 
            count(distinct task_2_3) as total
            from task_group
.... (and so on)
```

Is there any suggestion to solve this? Thanks a lot!

*Note for now I need at least 2/3 combination of task. Thank you

Comment: How did you get the expected output ? not clear what you are trying to do !

Comment: Specifically, how are you defining which tasks you want to combine into a single record? The values in the "combination" of your resultset seem to be random

Comment: I'm really sorry, i just finished editing my question, Is this clear? I have tried explain more. Let me know if it's still unclear

Comment: Hi - no, it's still not clear how you are coming up with those combinations. However (and this is based on me guessing that you want every possible combination of tasks) if you have 9 tasks then there are 100,000s of possible permutations of those tasks. Is that really what you are trying to achieve and what use is a dataset that large? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Thank you for the concern, the data is not too large it just maybe <1k user and 1 user will have 9 row it will be 9k row. My expected output is I can know the best combination of the task that can finished by user, and we will use this data for weekly reporting. Sorry i just add more explanation from my question, 2 or 3 combination is good for me.

Comment: --continue--  so my expected output will be like combination | total_user_completed. Then, I will took the best top 10 combination with the biggest total user completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so with a CTE for test data:

```
with data(user_id, task, is_completed, updated_at) as (
    select * from values
    (123, 'Task 1', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 2', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 3', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 4', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 5', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 6', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 7', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 8', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 9', 1, '2024-01-01'::date)
)
```

and a CTE for the combinations of 2:

```
), combinations_2 as (
    select
        a.user_id, 
        a.task || '_' || b.task as combi
    from data as a
    join data as b
        on a.user_id = b.user_id 
        --and a.updated_at = b.updated_at
        and a.is_completed = 1 and b.is_completed = 1
        and a.task < b.task
),
```

[image]

and a CTE for the 3's:

```
), combinations_3 as (
    select
        a.user_id, 
        a.task || '_' || b.task || '_' || c.task as combi
    from data as a
    join data as b
        on a.user_id = b.user_id 
        --and a.updated_at = b.updated_at
        and a.is_completed = 1 and b.is_completed = 1
        and a.task < b.task
    join data as c
        on a.user_id = c.user_id 
        --and a.updated_at = c.updated_at
        and a.is_completed = 1 and c.is_completed = 1
        and b.task < c.task
),
```

[image]

union those together:

```
), merged as (
    select * from combinations_2
    union all 
    select * from combinations_3
)
```

then count:

```
select 
    combi, 
    count(user_id) 
from merged
group by 1
order by 1;
```

[image]

Now you might want to use a CTE to filter the `is_completed = 0` rows, but that might also cause sync between the uses, and cause performance loss. Another method would be to build the 2 combi's and and also keep the `b.task` and then do the third round join against that, that might perform better.

I also assumed the updated_at are meaningless, and that there are not duplicate  dates for the same ID/Task, thus again it might be better to preprocess the data to remove those. Thus:

```
with data(user_id, task, is_completed, updated_at) as (
    select * from values
    (123, 'Task 1', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 2', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 3', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 4', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 5', 0, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 6', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 7', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 8', 1, '2024-01-01'::date),
    (123, 'Task 9', 1, '2024-01-01'::date)
), cleaned as (
    select distinct user_id, task
    from data
    where is_completed = 1
), combinations_2 as (
    select
        a.user_id, 
        a.task || '_' || b.task as combi
    from cleaned as a
    join cleaned as b
        on a.user_id = b.user_id 
        and a.task < b.task
), combinations_3 as (
    select
        a.user_id, 
        a.task || '_' || b.task || '_' || c.task as combi
    from cleaned as a
    join cleaned as b
        on a.user_id = b.user_id 
        and a.task < b.task
    join cleaned as c
        on a.user_id = c.user_id 
        and b.task < c.task
), merged as (
    select * from combinations_2
    union all 
    select * from combinations_3
)
select 
    combi, 
    count(user_id) 
from merged
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For MS SQL Server 2016: (Should work for Snowflake)

I think I have a way to get what you want. It requires manually specifying amount of permutations and will not create all of the possible ones. This would also create a pretty large table increasing exponentially as the number of tasks increases.

Here I have a working solution for 3 permutations of the task column. You can add more by adding to the code.

It works by getting the `DISTINCT` tasks and `CROSS JOINING` these on each other while also checking that a permutations doesn't exist more than once. Then we get the number of completed tasks and `LEFT JOIN` these on the permutations to get the completed amount of tasks per permutation

```
-- Create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    user_id INT,
    task VARCHAR(50),
    IS_COMPLETED BIT,
    updated_at DATE
);

-- Insert data into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempTable
(
    user_id,
    task,
    IS_COMPLETED,
    updated_at
)
VALUES
(123, 'Task 1', 1, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 2', 1, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 3', 0, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 4', 0, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 5', 0, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 6', 1, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 7', 1, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 8', 1, '2024-01-01'),
(123, 'Task 9', 1, '2024-01-01');

;with cteAllColumns
as (select DISTINCT
        Task as col
    from #TempTable
   )
-- See commented code for adding more permutations

select c1.col as 'c1.task',
       c2.col as 'c2.task',
       c3.col as 'c3.task',
       --c4.col as 'c4.task',
       ISNULL(SUM(result.completed), 0) as 'combination completed'
from cteAllColumns c1
    cross join cteAllColumns c2
    cross join cteAllColumns c3

    --cross join cteAllColumns c4

    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT task,
               COUNT(task) as 'completed'
        FROM #TempTable
        WHERE IS_COMPLETED = 1
        GROUP BY task
    ) result
        ON result.task = c1.col
           OR result.task = c2.col
           OR result.task = c3.col
--OR result.task = c4.col


where c1.col < c2.col
      AND c2.col < c3.col
--AND c3.col < c4.col

GROUP BY c1.col,
         c2.col,
         c3.col --,c4.col

ORDER BY c1.col,
         c2.col,
         c3.col --,c4.col


DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a table called `"tasks"` and insert data into it.

```
create table "tasks"(
  user_id int not null,
  "task" varchar(10) not null,
  IS_COMPLETED numeric(1) not null,
  updated_at date not null,
  primary key(user_id, "task")
);

insert into "tasks" values
  (42, 'Task 1', 1, '2023-12-29'),
  (42, 'Task 7', 1, '2023-12-29'),
  (42, 'Task 9', 0, '2023-12-29'),
  (123, 'Task 1', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 2', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 3', 0, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 4', 0, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 5', 0, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 6', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 7', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 8', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (123, 'Task 9', 1, '2024-01-01'),
  (170, 'Task 7', 1, '2024-01-09'),
  (170, 'Task 8', 1, '2024-01-09');
```

The result set of the `b` CTE contains rows for completed tasks. The `pow()` function raises `2` to the power of the `dense_rank()` window function for further using in the `bitand()` function.

```
with recursive
  b as (
    select
      user_id, updated_at, "task",
      pow(2, dense_rank() over(partition by user_id, updated_at
                               order by "task")-1) as pow2
    from "tasks"
    where is_completed = 1
  ),
```

The `u` CTE combains rows of the `b` CTE with rows of the `b` CTE for all values of the `user_id` column with of the `b` CTE rows for all values of the `updated_at` column with rows of the `b` CTE for all values of the `"task"` column. For all rows, the `pow()` function raises 2 to the power of the window function `dense_rank()` for later use in the `bitand()` function.

```
  u as (
    select user_id, updated_at, "task", pow2 from b
    union all
    select
      0, updated_at, "task",
      pow(2, dense_rank() over(partition by updated_at
                               order by "task")-1) as pow2
    from b
    union all
    select
      user_id, '0'::date, "task",
      pow(2, dense_rank() over(partition by user_id
                               order by "task")-1) as pow2
    from b
    union all
    select 0, '0'::date, "task",
      pow(2, dense_rank() over(order by "task")-1) as pow2
    from b
  ),
```

In the `rec` CTE, for all combinations of values in the `user_id` and `update_at` columns, numbers are recursively generated from `0` to `2` in the power of the number of different tasks minus `1`.

```
  rec as (
    select
      user_id, updated_at,
      pow(2, count(distinct "task"))-1 as msk2
    from u
    group by user_id, updated_at
    union all
    select user_id, updated_at, msk2-1
    from rec
    where msk2 > 0
  ),
```

In the `res` CTE, the `u` CTE is joined with the `rec` CTE and the `u` CTE rows whose `u .pow2` bit is not set to `r .msk2` are eliminated.

```
  res as (
    select
      u.user_id, u.updated_at, u."task", r.msk2
    from u
    join rec as r
    on r.user_id = u.user_id and
       r.updated_at = u.updated_at
    where bitand(u.pow2, r.msk2) != 0
  )
```

Finally, using the `listagg()` function allows us to obtain chains of completed tasks for various combinations of `user_id` and `updated_at` column values.

```
select
  user_id, updated_at,
  listagg(distinct "task", '|') within group(order by "task") as combination,
  count(*) as total
from res
where user_id = 123 and updated_at != '0'::date
group by user_id, updated_at, msk2;
```

Results.

```
+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
| USER_ID | UPDATED_AT |                COMBINATION                | TOTAL |
+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 7                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 8               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1                                    |     1 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 7                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 7               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 8                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 7|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6                                    |     1 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 8|Task 9        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 7                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 7|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 8|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 7                                    |     1 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 7|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 7|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 7|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 7                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 7|Task 8                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 8|Task 9                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 9                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 9        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 9                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 7                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 7|Task 9                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 9                                    |     1 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 7|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 8                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 8|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 9                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9        |     5 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2                                    |     1 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 7|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 7|Task 8|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 8                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 7|Task 8               |     4 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 7                             |     2 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 2|Task 6|Task 7|Task 8|Task 9 |     6 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 1|Task 6|Task 8                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 2|Task 8|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 6|Task 7|Task 9                      |     3 |
|     123 | 2024-01-01 | Task 8                                    |     1 |
+---------+------------+-------------------------------------------+-------+
```